# How can I implement undo-redo for a QComboBox in PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qcombobox, undo-redo

There are many questions regarding the basics of `QUndoCommand` on StackOverflow, but I cannot find a minimal working example of undo/redo for a `QComboBox` in PyQt5, so I am trying to create one. However, I am stuck with segmentation fault errors with the code below.

**Questions**:

- What is wrong with this code?
- What needs to be changed to create a minimal working example?

**Goal**:

- Keyboard undo: `Ctrl` + `Z`
- Keyboard redo: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Z`

**To reproduce an error** (using code below)

- Launch app
- Change the combobox selection from "a" to "b"
- Press `Ctrl` + `Z` to undo (this correctly reverts to "a")
- Press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Z` to redo (this produces a segmentation fault)

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class MyUndoCommand(QtWidgets.QUndoCommand):
    def __init__(self, combobox, ind0, ind1):
        super().__init__()
        self.combobox = combobox
        self.ind0     = ind0
        self.ind1     = ind1

    def redo(self):
        self.combobox.setCurrentIndex( self.ind1 )

    def undo(self):
        self.combobox.setCurrentIndex( self.ind0 )


class MyComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.addItems( ['a', 'b', 'c'] )
        self.ind0  = 0
        self.undostack = QtWidgets.QUndoStack()
        self.currentIndexChanged.connect( self.on_index_changed )
    
    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        z         = e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Z
        ctrl      = e.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier
        ctrlshift = e.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier | QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier
        if ctrl and z:
            if self.undostack.canUndo():
                self.undostack.undo()
        if ctrlshift and z:
            if self.undostack.canRedo():
                self.undostack.redo()

    def on_index_changed(self, ind):
        cmd = MyUndoCommand(self, self.ind0, ind)
        self.undostack.push( cmd )
        self.ind0  = ind



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication( sys.argv )
    widget = MyComboBox()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you connected the `currentIndexChanged` signal to a function that creates an undo command no matter what, and since `MyUndoCommand` *does* change the current index, the result is that you get a recursive call for it.

A possible solution is to create a flag that is checked whenever the index is changed and does *not* create a further undo command whenever that index change is triggered by another undo/redo.

```
class MyComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    undoActive = False
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.addItems(['a', 'b', 'c'])
        self.ind0 = 0
        self.undostack = QtWidgets.QUndoStack()
        self.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_index_changed)
    
    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Z:
            ctrl = e.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier
            ctrlshift = e.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier | QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier
            if ctrl and self.undostack.canUndo():
                self.undoActive = True
                self.undostack.undo()
                self.undoActive = False
                return
            elif ctrlshift and self.undostack.canRedo():
                self.undoActive = True
                self.undostack.redo()
                self.undoActive = False
                return
        super().keyPressEvent(e)

    def on_index_changed(self, ind):
        if not self.undoActive:
            cmd = MyUndoCommand(self, self.ind0, ind)
            self.undostack.push( cmd )
        self.undoActive = False
        self.ind0 = ind
```

Note that I've changed the `keyPressEvent` handler in order to ensure that unhandled key events get processed, which is important for keyboard navigation and item selection.

Comment: Thanks!!  I understand the flow now, but this solution has more boolean variable setting and checking than I was expecting. I wonder if a more minimal solution is possible?

Comment: @ToddP 6 bool settings/checkings in the whole code are as minimal as you could get. There are other ways, obviously, but they wouldn't make it more minimal than that. The problem is in the `currentIndexChanged`, and since that could happen whenever the undo/redo is triggered, there's not a lot you can do about it.